# Regex for optional alphanumeric prefix and mandatory numeric suffix

Tags: regex, alphanumeric, digit

I am trying to build a regular expression which goal is to follow 3 rules:

*(1) If the input is alphanumeric and it could be split into two groups containing letters and numbers, then letters are prefix and numbers are suffix. For example:*

**input: ABC123**

**output: prefix = ABC, suffix = 123**

*(2) If the input is numeric only, then there is no prefix, only suffix.
    For example:*

**input: 123**

**output: prefix = '', suffix = 123**

*(3) If the input is mixed alphanumeric, then all numbers to each other at the end of input are suffix and all other characters are prefix*

**input: A9B9C123**

**output: prefix = A9B9C, suffix = 123**

---

I have tried this so far:

```
"(?P<prefix>\D*)(?P<suffix>\d*)"
```

This matches rules (1) and (2) but NOT (3).

```
"(?P<prefix>.*)(?P<suffix>[0-9]+)"
```

This matches rule (3), but breaks rules (1) and (2).

Note: Input always ends with a number and prefix is optional.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors are must important here. `^.*?` will do a non-greedy match of zero or more characters until `(?P<number>[0-9]+)` the last number. And the last number is captured by the second group.

```
^(?P<prefix>.*?)(?P<number>[0-9]+)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zY2sZ5/5)